# C# HTML5 form submits when required fields are left empty

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I made a simple sign in form using HTML controls but running them at server side to use them in C#.

```
<button id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" type="submit" runat="server" onServerClick="btnSignIn_ServerClick">Sign in</button>
```

When I click it if the required fields are empty it still refreshes and it doesn't show the HTML5 validation.

```
<label for="txtUsername" class="sr-only" runat="server">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="txtUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" runat="server" required autofocus />
<label for="txtPassword" class="sr-only" runat="server">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" runat="server" required />
```

It works fine except when the fields are empty. It does that little refresh instead of showing the HTML5 alert that the field is empty.

**EDIT**
I managed to fix it by changing the button to input.

```
<input id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" type="submit" runat="server" onServerClick="btnSignIn_ServerClick" value="Sign In" />
```

Comment: are you running it in a browser that supports HTML5?

Comment: Yes. In fact the notification barely appears before the page refreshes.

Comment: Can you please look at the fiddle that I posted below. See if that's working on your side.

Comment: Did you mean asp.net rather than asp-classic?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I tagged too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9mk34evm/) fiddle and see if it helps. For me it is working correctly.

```
<form>
<label for="txtUsername" class="sr-only" runat="server">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" runat="server" required autofocus />
        <label for="txtPassword" class="sr-only" runat="server">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" runat="server" required />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm thinking it's because of the "onServerClick", but I want to confirm it. The fiddle works.

Comment: must be due to some other call on the server, possibly an ajax call that after  success does the redirect. As it is, the form is correct usage of HTML5 required attribute.

Comment: I fixed it. I changed it from button to input and it worked. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: A `<button type="submit">Sign In</button>` would also work.